# Search Box with predictive result

Tags: c#, .net, frontend

I want to create a search box that will show result relating to the typed the text. I am using .NET MVC and I have been stuck on this for awhile. I want to use the AlphaVantage API search endpoint to create this. [image]

It would like this. I just don't know what component to use or how to implement it.

Comment: Can you please add some code.

Comment: I want to say this behavior is generally referred to as a typeahead, which may also be in reference to the popular package/lib by that name.  basically, an autocomplete, autosuggest searching feature.

Answer (score 2):

As we don't know amount of your data and possible stack/budget in your project, **autocompletion**/**autosuggestion** could be implemented differently:

1. In memory (you break your word into all possible prefixes and map them to your entity through dictionary, could be optimized, like so - https://github.com/omerfarukz/autocomplete). Limit is around 10 million entries, a lot of memory consumption. Also support some storage mechanics, but I don't think it is more powerfull than fully fledged Lucene.
2. In Lucene index ([Lucene.Net (4.8) AutoComplete / AutoSuggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60417740/lucene-net-4-8-autocomplete-autosuggestion)). Limited to 2 billions, very optimized usage of memory, stored on hard drive or anywhere else. Hard to work with, because provide low-level micro optimizations on indexes and overall pipeline of tokenization/indexing.
3. In Elasticsearch cluster (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/suggest-usage.html). Unlimited, uses Lucene indexes as sharding units. Same as lucene, but every cloud infrastructure provide it for pretty penny.
4. In SQL using full text index ([SQL Server Full Text Catalog and Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275841/sql-server-full-text-catalog-and-autocomplete)). Limited by database providers such as SQLite/MSSQL/Oracle/etc, cheap, easy to use, usually consumes CPU as there is no tomorrow, but hey, it is relational, so you could join any data to results.

As to how to use it - basically you send request to desired framework instance and retrieve first N results, which then you serve in some REST GET response.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make a POST request ([HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)) to the API that will return your data. You'll also need to provide all required authorization information (whether headers or keys). That would need to be async or possibly a background worker so that it doesn't block your thread. The requests need to happen when there's a change in your search box.

You can probably find details on how to do the request [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-an-http-post-web-request).